# Queue or other methods to handle tick data?

Tags: redis, time-series, queue

In our electronic trading system, we need to do calculation based on tick data from 100+ contracts.

Tick data of contracts is not received in one message. One message only include tick data for one contract. Timestamp of contracts are slightly different (sometimes big diff, but let's ignore this case).

```
eg: (first column is timestamp. Second is contract name)
below 2 data has 1ms diff
10:34:03.235,10002007,510050C2006A03500  ,0.0546
10:34:03.236,10001909,510050C2003A02750  ,0.3888

below 2 data has 3ms diff
10:34:03.594,10002154,510300C2003M03700  ,0.4985
10:34:03.597,10002118,510300C2001M03700  ,0.4514
```

Only those with price change will have data. So I can't count contract number to know if I have received all data for this tick.

But on the other hand, we don't want to wait till we receive all data for the tick, because sometimes data could be late for long time, we will want to exclude them.

Low latency is required. So I think we will define a window - say 50 ms - and start to calculate based on whatever data we received in past 50ms.

What will be the best way to handle such use case?

Originally I want to use redis stream to maintain a small queue, that whenever a contract's data is received, I will push it to redis stream. But I couldn't figure out what's the best way to pull data as soon as specific time (say 50ms) passed.

I am thinking about maybe I should use some other technicals?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Sounds like Redis streams should do the trick. Can you elaborate on what issue you are having using Redis streams?

Comment: i am actually not very familiar with redis stream yet. I know it works like a queue but how could I make it work like this:   check messages in the queue, if (latest timestamp - newest timstamp) > threshold, read all these messages? Does redis stream support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XRANGE myStream - + COUNT 1` to get the first entry.

Use `XREVRANGE myStream + - COUNT 1` to get the last entry.

`XINFO STREAM myStream` also brings first and last entry, but [the docs](https://redis.io/commands/xinfo) say it is `O(log N)`.

Assuming you are using a timestamp as ID, or as a field, then you can compute the time difference.

If you are using Redis Streams auto-ID (`XADD myStream * ...`), the first part of the ID is the UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.

Assuming the above, you can do the check atomically with a Lua script:

```
EVAL "local first = redis.call('XRANGE', KEYS[1], '-', '+', 'COUNT', '1') local firstTime = {} if next(first) == nil then     return redis.error_reply('Stream is empty or key doesn`t exist') end for str in string.gmatch(first[1][1], '([^-]+)') do     table.insert(firstTime, tonumber(str)) end local last = redis.call('XREVRANGE', KEYS[1], '+', '-', 'COUNT', '1') local lastTime = {} for str in string.gmatch(last[1][1], '([^-]+)') do     table.insert(lastTime, tonumber(str)) end local ms = lastTime[1] - firstTime[1] if ms >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then     return redis.call('XRANGE', KEYS[1], '-', '+') else     return redis.error_reply('Only '..ms..' ms') end" 1 myStream 50
```

The arguments are `numKeys(1 here) streamKey timeInMs(50 here)`: `1 myStream 50`.

Here a friendly view of the Lua script:

```
local first = redis.call('XRANGE', KEYS[1], '-', '+', 'COUNT', '1')
local firstTime = {}
if next(first) == nil then
    return redis.error_reply('Stream is empty or key doesn`t exist')
end
for str in string.gmatch(first[1][1], '([^-]+)') do
    table.insert(firstTime, tonumber(str))
end
local last = redis.call('XREVRANGE', KEYS[1], '+', '-', 'COUNT', '1')
local lastTime = {}
for str in string.gmatch(last[1][1], '([^-]+)') do
    table.insert(lastTime, tonumber(str))
end
local ms = lastTime[1] - firstTime[1]
if ms >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
    return redis.call('XRANGE', KEYS[1], '-', '+')
else
    return redis.error_reply('Only '..ms..' ms')
end
```

It returns:

- `` (error) Stream is empty or key doesn`t exist ``
- `(error) Only 34 ms` if we don't have the required time elapsed
- The actual list of entries if the required time between first and last message has elapsed.

Make sure to check [Introduction to Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) to get familiar with Redis Streams, and [EVAL command](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to learn about Lua scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this will be able to meet my requirement!